# How to test properties of random generator

Tags: scala, unit-testing, random, scalatest

Using Scala, I've a method that return a set of 5 random numbers, that should be between 1 and a constant LIMIT.

What's the best approach to test that a answer will never return more/less than 5 elements, and all elements are between 1 and LIMIT? Making a simple test is easy. But should I make a loop of, lets say, 1000 iterations to better test it? Or there is some feature in unit testing for such cases?

Using `Scala` and `ScalaTest.FunSuite`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/147134/how-should-i-test-randomness

My approach would be to generate 100 sets for the limit 20 and test if the occurrences of each number are nearly equally divided.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try [QuickTheories](https://github.com/NCR-CoDE/QuickTheories) - property based testing framework.
It runs tests with many different possible generated input.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.